# How to verify if a e-mail is registered on Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my BotaoConfig activity, the idea here, is to catch a text from a EditText, verify if this e-mail exists in Base64 format in Firebase server, and if the e-mail exists, the app let the user advance to another activity, and if not, a Toast message will appear.

This method, validar contato, happens when a button is pressed, i activated on the button the property onClick.

The only thing that is not working is this if   if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) it's else is working and the another if, if there is nothing written is working to, the dificult like i said, is verify if the user exists.

```
package br.com.projeto.fetin.projeto;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import br.com.projeto.fetin.projeto.config.ConfiguracaoFirebase;
import br.com.projeto.fetin.projeto.helper.Base64Custom;
import br.com.projeto.fetin.projeto.model.Usuario;

public class BotaoConfig extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText emailDigitado;
private String identificadorContato;
private DatabaseReference firebase;
private Usuario usuario;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_botao_config);

    emailDigitado = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_cadastrar_usuario);
}

public void abrirChat(View view)
{
    usuario = new Usuario();
    usuario.setEmail( emailDigitado.getText().toString() );
    validarContato();
}

private void validarContato()
{
    //String emailContato = emailDigitado.getText().toString();
    firebase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("usuarios").child(usuario.getEmail());

    if( usuario.getEmail().isEmpty() ){
        Toast.makeText(BotaoConfig.this, "Preencha o e-mail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{

        //Verificar se o usuário já está cadastrado no nosso App
        identificadorContato = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(usuario.getEmail());

        //Recuperar instância Firebase
        firebase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("usuarios").child(identificadorContato);

        firebase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(BotaoConfig.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(BotaoConfig.this, "Usuário não possui cadastro.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

}

This is my usuário class that i am using on the previous one

```
package br.com.projeto.fetin.projeto.model;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;

import br.com.projeto.fetin.projeto.config.ConfiguracaoFirebase;

public class Usuario {
```

When

```
private String id;
private String nome;
private String email;
private String senha;
private int flag;
//private String senha1;

public Usuario(){

}

public void salvar(){
    DatabaseReference referenciaFirebase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();
    referenciaFirebase.child("usuarios").child(getId()).setValue(this);
}

public int getFlag() {
    return flag;
}

public void setFlag(int flag) {
    this.flag = flag;
}

@Exclude //para não salvar id ou senha no banco de dados usamos essa anotação
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}
/*@Exclude
public String getSenha1() {
    return senha1;
}

public void setSenha1(String senha) {
    this.senha1 = senha;
}*/
```

}

Here we have the logcat, when i enter with an e-mail that is subscribed on Firebase, and the app crashes

```
21/br.com.projeto.fetin.projeto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: br.com.projeto.fetin.projeto, PID: 15621
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201) 
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
   Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: n.ribeiro.cunha.azevedo100@gmail.com. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamx.zztj(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
      at br.com.projeto.fetin.projeto.BotaoConfig.validarContato(BotaoConfig.java:47)
      at br.com.projeto.fetin.projeto.BotaoConfig.abrirChat(BotaoConfig.java:41)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201) 
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

And lastly my Firebase Database structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCxpi.png)

Comment: Sorry by my bad english i tried

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you what's wrong:

> Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: n.ribeiro.cunha.azevedo100@gmail.com. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

You can't use email addresses as keys in Realtime Database because they contain invalid characters.

Comment: The typical approach is to encode the `.` from the email address as a `,`, since commas as (conveniently) not allowed in email addresses, but are allowed in Firebase database paths.

Comment: Sugestion how to change it ?